# how to convert a string to a Unix timestamp in ExtJS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to convert a string "24.05.2020 15:34:00" into a Unix timestamp in javascript. Can any one tell how to do that? thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be this exact string, or can it also be something like 'May 24, 2020 15:34:00' or any other format that complies with RFC 2822 timestamps or ISO8601?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with combination of `Ext.Date.parse` and `Ext.Date.format`.

`Ext.Date.parse` to make Date Object from String

`Ext.Date.format` to make timestamp from Date Object.

Ex.

```
Ext.Date.format(Ext.Date.parse("24.05.2020 15:34:00", "d.m.Y H:i:s"), "time");
```

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript:

```js
var s="24.05.2020 15:34:00".split(' ');  
var d=s[0].split('.');  
var t=s[1].split(':');
var jt=new Date(d[2],d[1]-1,d[0],t[0],t[1]);
var ut=jt.getTime()/1000;
console.log(ut);
```

On line 4 d [1] -1 because we count months from 0